# Upload Image on Firebase Storage Using Python

Tags: python, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I am using python library PyAutogui to take screenshots and I want to upload screenshot on Firebase without saving it in folder, I pasted my code what actually I am doing

```py
myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
name = dt_string+".png"
myScreenshot.save(name)
```

last line `myScreenShot.save(name)` is saving the screenshot in a folder then I upload it on database using this below code

```py
bucket = storage.bucket()
blob = bucket.blob(picname)
blob.upload_from_filename(
     imagePath,
     content_type='image/png',)
```

I don't want to save screenshot in folder, is there anyway to directly upload screenshot on Firebase storage without saving it locally.

Answer (score -1):

See https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html for the full API reference. Look at the `upload_from_string()` method that accepts raw `bytes`.